# How wire grid polarizers reflect light

Tags: optics

I know that only light with polarization in the plane of the "stripe" gets reflected.
What i need to know is if a single metal stripe could reflect such polarised light at ONLY the angle equal to the angle of incidence or do only a whole array of stripes produce specular reflections?

Sources are welcome

Thank you

Comment: You're describing a wire-grid polarizer. Not all polarizers behave the same way. You should be a bit more specific in your question.

Comment: I've changed the title now. Do you maybe have some knowledge to share on the topic?

Comment: Well, a singular metal strip won't be much of a polarizer. It will be more akin to a single slit diffraction with a central dark spot instead of a central bright spot.

Comment: So with "light" you mean microwaves?

Comment: Yes, i mean microwaves, and the polarizer was just an example. The core question is if a single stripe with subwavelength width but length of very many wavelengths can reflect specularly (according to law of reflection) or does it reflect diffusely. The polarization is in the plane of the wire length.

Answer (score 3):

When microwaves pass through a set of parallel conductors whose separation is of the order of the wavelength of the microwaves and whose length much larger than the wavelength of the microwaves the emerging microwaves are plane polarised.
Perhaps surprisingly, the plane of polarisation of the emerging microwaves is at right angles to the orientation of the parallel conductors.

The diagram below shows the electric field variation.

[image]

The reason for this is that microwaves whose plane of polarisation is parallel to the conductors induce currents in the conductors causing ohmic heating and in doing so are absorbed by the conductors.
Microwaves whose plane of polarisation is perpendicular to the parallel conductors induce significantly smaller currents and hence little of the microwave energy is absorbed.

[Polaroid filters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polaroid_(polarizer)) for use with light work on a similar principle except that the parallel conductors are long polymer chain molecules impregnated with iodine.
The scale of conductor separation is much smaller than that for microwaves as the wavelength of light is much smaller than that of microwaves.

This sort of diagram which is often used to demonstrate polarisation of waves on a string with the aid of slots cut into a pair of cards is at best misleading in the case of microwaves and the demonstration with parallel wires.

[image]